# Scala: fold over two-dimensional array

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given a potentially large image (or two-dimensional array of numbers), I'd like to loop over all the pixels (or numbers) and e.g. count all the black ones (or 0 values).

I know I can simply use a for comprehension like

```
for (y <- 0 until img.height; x <- 0 until img.width) {
    ...
}
```

but then I need a mutable variable for the count.  Which may not really be a problem, but suppose I don't want this and would like to use a more functional style, how do I do this without creating a large data structure with width x height elements (in other words keeping the memory-efficiency of the `0 until img.height` and `0 until img.width` ranges)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map over the collection, transforming inner ones into subcounts, and then sum those :

```
scala> val m = Array(
         Array("B","B","W"),
         Array("W","W","B"),
         Array("W","W","W")
       )
m: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(B, B, W), Array(W, W, B), Array(W, W, W))

scala> m.map(_.count(_ == "B")).sum
res0: Int = 3
```

---

**EDIT**

You can create a `Stream` using

```
Stream.tabulate(img.height, img.width)(identity)
```

and then use

```
stream.count(isBlack)
```

Note that [`Stream.tabulate`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$) accepts up to 5 dimensions (as its first argument).

Comment: Just to remind you that `"abc" == "abc"` does not work.

Comment: An image isn't a collection.  I added the two-dimensional array part because I don't need info on how to use e.g. BufferedImage from Scala, just anything that can be used to look up a pair of coordinates.  So, I guess I need something that starts from the x and y ranges.

Also, I'd prefer a generic answer that would work for more than two dimensions as well, and still be memory-efficient.  I think I should convert the ranges to streams, but don't know how to proceed from there.

Comment: `==` in scala is equivalent to `.equals` in Java.  To get reference equality you'd use Scala's `eq` operator, as in `if("abc" eq "abc")`

Comment: +1 for teaching me about tabulate.  I guess instead of `identity` I should use a function that looks up the color for the (Int, Int) right?

Comment: Obviously depends on your application, but yes, either `(Int,Int) => Color` or `(Int,Int) => Pixel` seems sensible.

Comment: Accepting this answer since for this particular purpose `Stream.tabulate` is the simplest.  But @Kolmar's answer is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for comprehension with ranges to convert an image to a sequence of pixels:

```
for {
    y <- 0 until img.height
    x <- 0 until img.width
} yield image(x, y)
```

But this will create a full sequence in memory. To make it lazy you may take views of the ranges:

```
for {
    y <- (0 until img.height).view
    x <- (0 until img.width).view
} yield image(x, y)
```

With that you may call higher-level functions on this sequence to calculate what you need:

```
(
    for {
        y <- (0 until img.height).view 
        x <- (0 until img.width).view
    } yield image(x, y)
).count(_.isBlack)
```

You may, of course, add this conversion to a pixel sequence as an implicit method of your image class:

```
implicit class ImageOperations(image: Image) {
    def toPixelSeq = for {
        y <- (0 until img.height).view 
        x <- (0 until img.width).view
    } yield image(x, y)
}
```

Comment: This seems similar to what I had in mind with streams, but views may be better since I want to prevent memoization anyway.